# Passing structures to functions on a recursive program. How to fix compile error C2664?

Tags: c

I am trying to pass structures to functions in recursive program. I'm not sure if the structures are passing to the functions.

```
// poker calls interleave
// interleave calls helper

void interleave(CardDeck *leftDeck, CardDeck *rightDeck);

void poker(CardDeck origDeck);

void helper(CardDeck *leftDeck, CardDeck *rightDeck, CardDeck *currentDeck);

void poker(CardDeck origDeck)
{
    CardDeck leftDeck =     
    {
        leftDeck.cards[MAX_SIZE] = {0}, 
        leftDeck.size = MAX_SIZE
    };

    CardDeck rightDeck =        
    {
        rightDeck.cards[MAX_SIZE] = {0},    
        rightDeck.size = MAX_SIZE
    };
}
void interleave(CardDeck  *leftDeck, CardDeck  *rightDeck)
{
    int leftloop = leftDeck->size;
    int rightloop = rightDeck->size;
    //ger error when I try to call helper
    helper(*leftDeck, *rightDeck, &currentDeck);
}

void helper(CardDeck leftDeck, CardDeck rightDeck, CardDeck *currentDeck)
{
    int leftFlag;
    int rightFlag;
    leftFlag = 20;
    rightFlag =30;
}
```

Keep getting error with the call helper function. Added some more code to clarify. Thanks.

Comment: Please post the error you're receiving.

Comment: Please provide a [example], and please raise the warning level of your compiler to the max - and change your code until all warnings and errors are gone.

Answer (score 0):

Your function helper has been prototyped as `void helper(CardDeck *leftDeck, CardDeck *rightDeck, CardDeck  *currentDeck)` that means it takes as first argument a `CardDeck *`, as second argument `CardDeck *` and lastly another `CardDeck *`

and the prototype definition as `void helper(CardDeck leftDeck, CardDeck rightDeck, CardDeck * currentDeck)` which does not match the previous prototype. To fix your problem, try adding `*` to both `leftDec` and `rightDeck` so it matches the prototype.